# I need to create a Shell, that utilizes jq to extract some data from a rather large json file

Tags: json, jq

So I'm struggling to solve this problem.

This is part of the data from the JSON file. The rest of the data is using the same structure.

```
  {
  "data": {
  "infra01.xx.mdk.services": {
    "etcd": [],
    "kubeconfigs": [],
    "meta": {
      "checked_at_time": "2023-01-30 18:14:56.013633",
      "show_all": "True",
      "warn_before_date": "2024-01-30 18:14:56.013633",
      "warning_days": 365
    },
    "ocp_certs": [
      {
        "cert_cn": "xxxxxxxxx:",
        "days_remaining": 1126,
        "expiry": "2026-03-02 09:49:43",
        "health": "ok",
        "issuer": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "path": "/etc/origin/node/client-ca.crt",
        "serial": 1,
        "serial_hex": "0x1"
      },
      {
        "cert_cn": "xxxxxxxxx:",
        "days_remaining": 1126,
        "expiry": "2026-03-02 09:49:43",
        "health": "ok",
        "issuer": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "path": "/etc/origin/node/client-ca.crt",
        "serial": 1,
        "serial_hex": "0x1"
      }
    ],
    "registry": [],
    "router": []
  },
  "infra02.xx.mdk.services": {
    "etcd": [
      {
        "cert_cn": "xxxxxxxxx:",
        "days_remaining": 1126,
        "expiry": "2026-03-02 09:49:43",
        "health": "ok",
        "issuer": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "path": "/etc/origin/node/client-ca.crt",
        "serial": 1,
        "serial_hex": "0x1"
      }
    ],
    "kubeconfigs": [],
    "meta": {
      "checked_at_time": "2023-01-30 18:14:56.253790",
      "show_all": "True",
      "warn_before_date": "2024-01-30 18:14:56.253790",
      "warning_days": 365
    },
    "ocp_certs": [
      {
        "cert_cn": "xxxxxxxxx:",
        "days_remaining": 1126,
        "expiry": "2026-03-02 09:49:43",
        "health": "ok",
        "issuer": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "path": "/etc/origin/node/client-ca.crt",
        "serial": 1,
        "serial_hex": "0x1"
      }
    ],
    "registry": [],
    "router": []
  },
  "infra03.xx.mdk.services": {
    "etcd": [],
    "kubeconfigs": [],
    "meta": {
      "checked_at_time": "2023-01-30 18:14:56.557721",
      "show_all": "True",
      "warn_before_date": "2024-01-30 18:14:56.557721",
      "warning_days": 365
    },
    "ocp_certs": [
      {
        "cert_cn": "xxxxxxxxx:",
        "days_remaining": 1126,
        "expiry": "2026-03-02 09:49:43",
        "health": "ok",
        "issuer": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "path": "/etc/origin/node/client-ca.crt",
        "serial": 1,
        "serial_hex": "0x1"
      },
      {
        "cert_cn": "xxxxxxxxx:",
        "days_remaining": 1126,
        "expiry": "2026-03-02 09:49:43",
        "health": "ok",
        "issuer": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "path": "/etc/origin/node/client-ca.crt",
        "serial": 1,
        "serial_hex": "0x1"
      }
    ],
    "registry": [],
    "router": []
  }
  }
  }
```

I tried to write a shell that uses jq to extract the following data:

```
"master-services(name of master Service)":
      host1:....
        cert_cn:....
        days_remaining:....
        expiry:.......
      host2:.....
        cert_cn:....
        days_remaining:....
        expiry:.......
```

And so on... I've gotten as far as extracting the data of host1, cert_cn etc… but I just can't get the master service name in front of the belonging data. I think it is because the master Service name is in {} brackets and therefore defined as an object, rather than an array...
Furthermore, I've tried
if anybody has any tips, I would be really grateful…

Also, first time posting, so if anything else is needed, or I need to remove something, please tell me!

Edit:
So to clarify, there are multiple "master.services", with multiple "host"s. I need a jq command, that will be executable in a shell, that outputs:
the "master.service" (so that the certificate that will be running out is identifyable), followed by the hosts, followed by only "cert_cn", "days_remaining" and "expiry", as shown above.
The output needs to be in xml format, but that problem will be approached, after i solved this. The problems i had so far, are the dots in "master.service" which made it impossible to to directly adress them. After that i tried to navigate through the json by doin something like:
`jq -r '.data | .[1] | {cert_cn, days_remaining, expiry}'`
But because the "master.service" is in "{}" brackets instead of in [] brackets, i cant index them with numbers, because they are objects rather than arrays.

So to clarify i edited the example code to be a valid json file. Also now it should be clearer to understand my problem. I am really learning and exercising right now. So thats the reason im going step by step to get a better understanding. My Problem right now is, that I have created a loop, that reads the the master service name, and right now im working on only printing out the nth(master.service), that will be printed out and passed on so jq can then print out the belonging "cert_cn, days_remaining" and the "expiry" date. After that it should go "back" to the next master.serice and start printing out the next "cert_cn, days_remaining, expiry". Im progressing slowly. So if anyone has a idea, i would be grateful.
Already thanks for the comments and sorry for the unclearly formulated question, still working on my english..

Comment: Please remove jquery tag since this is not related to jquery at all.

Comment: What do you mean with "create a shell"? Do you want to write a shell _script_? Do you want the jq program? Do you need to write a jq REPL? How are you going to use this shell/REPL? What is your expected output format (if any)?

Comment: Yes i want to write a shell script. The final output needs to be in xml format, but this is not a problem. The usage will be that the monitoring program of the servercluster, from which these certificates come, will be able to alarm you if a certificate is expiring soon.

Comment: @Nepromukk please [edit] the question to clarify this. Also include the expected output. Right now, it reads as if you are trying to implement an interactive shell wrapper around jq (a REPL)

Comment: Also, your JSON is not valid. It helps immensely to add a [mre] to the question, because it makes a lot easier for others to post helpful answers.

Comment: And your input contains multiple hosts, yet your output only a single entry – how do you plan on merging/aggregating them? Are the indents in the output significant? Do you want to produce text output or JSON output? (because the input JSON pretty much already has your output structure, plus a few more properties)

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like `.data | ."master.services" |= map_values(map({cert_cn, days_remaining, expiry}))` or `.data | ."master.services" |= map_values(first|{cert_cn, days_remaining, expiry})`? I have to guess here. If you [edit] the question to include more detail, somebody might be able to answer.

Comment: "host1" has multiple "cert_cn" properties. Which one should be displayed? And if you need XML, why transform to something else first? Why not output XML in the first place? No offense, but it sounds to me like you are tackling this problem from the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample file you have given above is not a valid JSON. Contains non-quoted strings, missing open braces and several missing closing braces. A right one is here (lets suppose is is a file named `duda_jq_stackoverflow.json`.

If you execute

```
oscar@toreyes-i7:/tmp$ cat duda_jq_stackoverflow.json
```

the shown content is:

```
{
    "data": {
         "master.services": {
             "host1": [
               {
                 "cert_cn": "CN=host1-signer1:",
                 "days_remaining": 412,
                 "expiry": "2024-03-18 17:21:41",
                 "health": "ok",
                 "issuer": "CN=host1-signer1",
                 "path": "/etc/host1/ca.crt",
                 "serial": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                 "serial_hex": "xxxxxxxx"
               },
               {
                 "cert_cn": "CN=host1-signer2",
                 "days_remaining": 544,
                 "expiry": "2024-07-28 12:47:50",
                 "health": "ok",
                 "issuer": "CN=host1-signer2",
                 "path": "/etc/host1/server.crt",
                 "serial": 12,
                 "serial_hex": "0xc"
               },
               {
                 "cert_cn": "CN=host3-signer1",
                 "days_remaining": 544,
                 "expiry": "2024-07-28 12:47:52",
                 "health": "ok",
                 "issuer": "CN=host3-signer1",
                 "path": "/etc/host3/peer.crt",
                 "serial": 14,
                 "serial_hex": "0xe"
               }
             ],
             "host4": [
               {
                 "cert_cn": "CN=host4-signer1",
                 "days_remaining": 729,
                 "expiry": "2025-01-29 17:10:11",
                 "health": "ok",
                 "issuer": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                 "path": "/etc/origin/master/admin.host4",
                 "serial": 6,
                 "serial_hex": "0x6"
               }
             ]
         }
    }
}
```

If you execute

```
oscar@toreyes-i7:/tmp$ jq '.data["master.services"]'  duda_jq_stackoverflow.json
```

you get the next fragment of the original JSON:

```json
{
  "host1": [
    {
      "cert_cn": "CN=host1-signer1:",
      "days_remaining": 412,
      "expiry": "2024-03-18 17:21:41",
      "health": "ok",
      "issuer": "CN=host1-signer1",
      "path": "/etc/host1/ca.crt",
      "serial": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
      "serial_hex": "xxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
      "cert_cn": "CN=host1-signer2",
      "days_remaining": 544,
      "expiry": "2024-07-28 12:47:50",
      "health": "ok",
      "issuer": "CN=host1-signer2",
      "path": "/etc/host1/server.crt",
      "serial": 12,
      "serial_hex": "0xc"
    },
    {
      "cert_cn": "CN=host3-signer1",
      "days_remaining": 544,
      "expiry": "2024-07-28 12:47:52",
      "health": "ok",
      "issuer": "CN=host3-signer1",
      "path": "/etc/host3/peer.crt",
      "serial": 14,
      "serial_hex": "0xe"
    }
  ],
  "host4": [
    {
      "cert_cn": "CN=host4-signer1",
      "days_remaining": 729,
      "expiry": "2025-01-29 17:10:11",
      "health": "ok",
      "issuer": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "path": "/etc/origin/master/admin.host4",
      "serial": 6,
      "serial_hex": "0x6"
    }
  ]
}
```

I recommend you to use the `gron` program to get the path you have to use with jq (in the output, remove the initial "json" part of each line).

You can get `gron` in https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron

If your execute the command

```
oscar@toreyes-i7:/tmp$ gron duda_jq_stackoverflow.json
```

you get

```
json = {};
json.data = {};
json.data["master.services"] = {};
json.data["master.services"].host1 = [];
json.data["master.services"].host1[0] = {};
json.data["master.services"].host1[0].cert_cn = "CN=host1-signer1:";
json.data["master.services"].host1[0].days_remaining = 412;
json.data["master.services"].host1[0].expiry = "2024-03-18 17:21:41";
json.data["master.services"].host1[0].health = "ok";
json.data["master.services"].host1[0].issuer = "CN=host1-signer1";
json.data["master.services"].host1[0].path = "/etc/host1/ca.crt";
json.data["master.services"].host1[0].serial = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
json.data["master.services"].host1[0].serial_hex = "xxxxxxxx";
json.data["master.services"].host1[1] = {};
json.data["master.services"].host1[1].cert_cn = "CN=host1-signer2";
json.data["master.services"].host1[1].days_remaining = 544;
json.data["master.services"].host1[1].expiry = "2024-07-28 12:47:50";
json.data["master.services"].host1[1].health = "ok";
json.data["master.services"].host1[1].issuer = "CN=host1-signer2";
json.data["master.services"].host1[1].path = "/etc/host1/server.crt";
json.data["master.services"].host1[1].serial = 12;
json.data["master.services"].host1[1].serial_hex = "0xc";
json.data["master.services"].host1[2] = {};
json.data["master.services"].host1[2].cert_cn = "CN=host3-signer1";
json.data["master.services"].host1[2].days_remaining = 544;
json.data["master.services"].host1[2].expiry = "2024-07-28 12:47:52";
json.data["master.services"].host1[2].health = "ok";
json.data["master.services"].host1[2].issuer = "CN=host3-signer1";
json.data["master.services"].host1[2].path = "/etc/host3/peer.crt";
json.data["master.services"].host1[2].serial = 14;
json.data["master.services"].host1[2].serial_hex = "0xe";
json.data["master.services"].host4 = [];
json.data["master.services"].host4[0] = {};
json.data["master.services"].host4[0].cert_cn = "CN=host4-signer1";
json.data["master.services"].host4[0].days_remaining = 729;
json.data["master.services"].host4[0].expiry = "2025-01-29 17:10:11";
json.data["master.services"].host4[0].health = "ok";
json.data["master.services"].host4[0].issuer = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
json.data["master.services"].host4[0].path = "/etc/origin/master/admin.host4";
json.data["master.services"].host4[0].serial = 6;
json.data["master.services"].host4[0].serial_hex = "0x6";
```

In that output, we can see the format of the paths to be used with `jq`. For example, if I take the line

```
json.data["master.services"] = {};
```

and remove the `json` at the beginning and discard everything from `=` onwards, what is left is:

```
.data["master.services"]
```

And that is the path to tell `jq` to extract the field value.

Note that as the field name has a `.` in it, you have to surround the field name with double quotes, and all this, in turn, with square brackets `[` and `]`.

You can get the values `host1` and `host4` ejecuting:

```
oscar@toreyes-i7:/tmp$ jq -r '.data["master.services"] | keys_unsorted | .[]'  duda_jq_stackoverflow.json
host1
host4
```

With that values, you can compose the paths and make another query using `jq`.

Or maybe this can be a starting point to get to what you want to achieve:

```
oscar@toreyes-i7:/tmp$ jq -r '.data["master.services"]["host1"][] as $nodo | "\("cert_cn = " + $nodo.cert_cn + "\n" + "days_remaining = " +  ($nodo.days_remaining | tostring) + "\n" + "expiry " + $nodo.expiry + "\n")"'  duda_jq_stackoverflow.json
cert_cn = CN=host1-signer1:
days_remaining = 412
expiry 2024-03-18 17:21:41

cert_cn = CN=host1-signer2
days_remaining = 544
expiry 2024-07-28 12:47:50

cert_cn = CN=host3-signer1
days_remaining = 544
expiry 2024-07-28 12:47:52
```

To execute the next script you have a create a file called `duda_jq_stackoverflow_2.json`, with the contents of your sample JSON:

```
FICHERO_JSON=duda_jq_stackoverflow_2.json

for CLAVE in $(jq -r '. as $datos | .data | keys_unsorted[] | select ( endswith(".services") )' $FICHERO_JSON)
do
    echo ==== $CLAVE =====
    # You have to include here all keys that may contain certificate
    # expiry data, or calculate them in another jq execution
    for CLAVE2 in etcd ocp_certs
    do
         echo "  === BEGIN $CLAVE - $CLAVE2 ===="
         jq -r ".data[\"$CLAVE\"].$CLAVE2[] | \"  cert = \(.cert_cn)\",\"  days_remaining = \(.days_remaining)\",\"  expiry = \(.expiry)\",\"  -----\" "  $FICHERO_JSON
         echo "  === END   $CLAVE - $CLAVE2 ===="
         echo
    done
    echo ====
    echo
done
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hi and thank you very  much for your answer. In the original document there are multiple "master services" with different names. The name is always using the same structure for example: "infra01.xx.xxx.services"..  Is there a way you can list these "masters services" by using only a fragment of the name?
Thank you very much!

Comment: @nepromukk send a valid JSON file as a sample, please.

Comment: You can get the field that end with ".services" in that file with: `$ cat duda_jq_stackoverflow.json | ./jq-win64.exe -r '.data | keys_unsorted[] | select ( endswith("services") )'`, that, in this case, returns `master.services`. With that values you can compose additional commands with jq.

Comment: I updated the example code, so it is a valid JSON file. Your comment really helped me so far to get the master.services. So thank you very much and I appreciate any other ideas.

Comment: @nepromukk, I've added a new fragment of code at the end of the answer, that shows the values related to certs, in keys "etcd" and "opc_certs". If there are other keys that can contain data about certs, you have to add them. in the second loop.

Comment: @Nepromukk,, another command that you can use to get the objects that contain data for certificates is: `cat duda_jq_stackoverflow_2.json | jq -r '.data[][][]|select(has("cert_cn")?)'`. Note the `?` to avoid errors.

Comment: With your help i was able to solve the problem with:
`jq ".data | keys_unsorted[]" $input_file | awk -v line="$count" 'NR == line {print}'
 // jq ".data | nth($count; .[]) |.ocp_certs[] | {cert_cn, days_remaining}"`
First line reads the master.service Name, i've also embedded its output into a variable. Second line prints the requested cert_cn and days_remaining, also embedded into a variable.
Thank you very much for your help and your very kind way of handling my questions!